# How to handle/diagnose command exit with error 137 in jenkins when running npm install

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, npm-install

I have a stage in jenkins pipeline that runs a script to install npm packages into a k8s container. The problem is, sometimes the build - that stage - fails, sometimes it passes. And I can never predict when.

I did a bit of research and I think it's NPM memory issue but am not sure.

My question is `How to handle/diagnose command exit with error 137 in jenkins when running npm install?`

or what could be the issue?

Comment: Are there any logs? Is there enough memory on the node? Do you have any limits set on pods?

Comment: @MariuszK. It turned out that builds in Jenkins were consuming a lot of memory at a particular stage. If they happened to run many of them, the system was going out of memory